# AES Encryption using 256 bit hex key

Tags: aes

Is there any way or sample through which we can acheive AES Encrypt using 256 bit hex key.
Also what are the specifications for a 256 bit hex key. (also does it have to do with the character length).

Comment: ... and what's so special about 256 bit key? I'm not following what you're trying to ask. 256 bit key == hexadecimal string of length 64.

Comment: @JosephH: One can only have a 128, 192, or 256 bit key for AES.  Rijndael allows any number of bits that is a multiple of 32, with a minimum of 128.

Comment: @EricJ.: if you were to write down 256bit in hexadecimal form, it's a string with a length of 64. I was wondering what exactly he's asking

Comment: @JosephH: 256 bits / 8 bits/byte = 32 bytes, not 64.

Comment: I'm sure that you know what I mean by "hexadecimal **string**"

Comment: Note that he said "**character length**". Other than hexadecimal string, what kind of representation of "hex key" involve "**character length**"

Comment: @ EricJ and @JosephH: You are both trying to read the OPs mind. I've  seen both interpretations. In my opinion, if the OP can't or won't clarify then the question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a 256 bit key for AES, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_cipher

On many platforms one character is 8 bits, so 256 bits would be the same as 32 characters (32 bytes).  Note that in .NET a `char` is actually 16 bits, using [UTF-16 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

An example depends on the platform you're doing AES on.  You can find an overview of implementations by platform here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations

Here's an example for .NET with a 256 bit key length:

http://www.gutgames.com/post/AES-Encryption-in-C.aspx

Comment: I am interested in .Net platform.

Comment: @pravin: Added a .NET example to my answser.